# compiler misinterprets my code and adds an extra "const" to argument

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, function-pointers

I'm stuck on a compiler error and I can't seem to find a solution online (mainly because google can't handle the syntax). This is the one and only error I'm getting (MVS 2005).

```
error C2664: 'LinkedList<T>::CreateLinkedList' : cannot convert parameter 2  
from 'const MemberInfo *' to 'MemberInfo *const *'  memberdata.cpp  59
```

The error points to this piece of code.

```
ILinkedList*
MemberData::CreateLinkedList()
{
    const MemberInfo* mi = this->get(FIRST);
    LinkedList<MemberInfo*>::CreateLinkedList(
        MemberInfo::CompareByTime,
        mi);

    return NULL;
}
```

The relevant pieces of code in this are:

MemberInfo class

```
// MemberInfo declaration
class
MemberInfo
{
    public:
        static int
        CompareByTime(
            const void* mi1,
            const void* mi2);
};

// MemberInfo implementation
int
MemberInfo::CompareByTime(
    const void* mi1,
    const void* mi2)
{
    if ( mi1 == NULL || mi2 == NULL )
        return 0;

    if ( ((MemberInfo*)mi1)->m_Time > ((MemberInfo*)mi2)->m_Time )
        return 1;
    if ( ((MemberInfo*)mi2)->m_Time > ((MemberInfo*)mi1)->m_Time )
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

LinkedList class

```
typedef int (*ComparatorFcn)(const void*, const void*);

template <class T>
class LinkedList
    : public ILinkedList
{
    private:
    protected:
        const T*
        m_ptValue;

        ComparatorFcn
        m_pCompFcn;

        LinkedList(
            const T* ptVal,
            ComparatorFcn func);

    public:
        static ILinkedList*
        CreateLinkedList(
            ComparatorFcn func, 
            const T* ptVal)
        {
            LinkedList<T>* t = new LinkedList<T>(ptVal, func);

            return t;
        }

        virtual
        ~LinkedList();

        LinkedList<T>*
        AddLink(
            T* pLink);

        virtual bool
        Remove();

        virtual bool
        RemoveLink(
            ILinkedList* pLink);

};
```

I'm quite stuck. I don't understand why the compiler thinks that my argument for the function `CreateLinkedList` is `MemberInfo *const *`rather than how I declared it as `const MemberInfo*` (or `const T*` actually).

Any help ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 is pretty outdated. maybe you can get more modern compiler?

Comment: Wow. A comparator function pointer taking `const void*`? A home-rolled linked list? Amazed your compiler doesn't vomit it back up apart from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `LinkedList<MemberInfo*>` should be `LinkedList<MemberInfo>`.

Notice that the error message mentions `MemberInfo *const *` - a pointer to a pointer.

As the type you use to instantiate the template is a `MemberInfo *`, T will be `MemberInfo *` and the `CreateLinkedList` functions expects a `T const *` aka a `MemberInfo * const *`.

The type you pass is a `MemberInfo const *` aka `const MemberInfo  *`.

So, you're asking the compiler to convert from `const MemberInfo  *` to `MemberInfo * const *`

Comment: yes! you're right. it compiles now. Gonna clean it up now using the comments posted here. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple problems:

First, your `MemberInfo::CompareByTime()` function is written wrong.  The way you have written it throws away any type checking the compiler can do. Better would be:

```
int MemberInfo::CompareByTime(const MemberInfo& mi1, const MemberInfo& mi2)
{
    if(mi1.m_Time > mi2.m_Time)
        return 1;
    if(mi1.m_Time < mi2.m_Time)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Second, pass the comparison function into your linked list as a template parameter:

```
template <class T, int (*CompFcn)(const T&, const T&)>
class LinkedList: public ILinkedList
```

Third, there's no reason to hide the constructor and wrap it in a static function that returns the superclass' pointer. C++ will automatically convert an object's pointer to a pointer to its superclass when needed. Also, you should be passing the contained values around by reference (instead of pointer) and store them by value when possible; if you want your container to store pointers, then just set `T` to a pointer type.  So your construction simplifies to:

```
protected:
    T m_ptValue;

public:
    LinkedList(const T& ptVal);
```

Finally, your code for `MemberData::CreateLinkedList` is broken. It always returns `NULL`. That is, from the outside it looks like it never creates a linked list. Also, the `this->` does nothing. What you should have is:

```
LinkedList<MemberInfo*, MemberInfo::CompareByTime>* MemberData::CreateLinkedList()
{
    return new LinkedList<MemberInfo*, MemberInfo::CompareByTime>(get(FIRST));
}
```

Though it's probably good practice to define `typedef LinkedList<MemberInfo*, MemberInfo::CompareByTime> LinkedListType;` in `MemberData`, which lets us write:

```
MemberData::LinkedListType* MemberData::CreateLinkedList()
{
    return new LinkedListType(get(FIRST));
}
```

Note that the return value will be typecast to `ILinkedList*` automatically where needed.

Comment: okay, thank you! I hadn't thought of passing the comparator function as a template argument. which is mainly the reason why I had to use void* as argument types because it makes no sense to specify a type if you're making a generic template class. Yeah the NULL pointer and this-> is there for debugging reasons.

Comment: "Yeah the NULL pointer and this-> is there for debugging reasons." ... Put that in code comments so you don't throw us for a loop next time. ;p And yeah, learning that template parameters don't have to be classes (recommended practice is to say `typename` instead of `class` these days), but can be any type that the compiler can figure out at compile time, is an eye-opener. In FIFO containers, for example, I usually have a `size_t Depth` template parameter which sets the size of an internal array. There's also traits classes, which could be useful here, but I don't want to overload you...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no difference between `const T` and `T const`. It is allowed to add the const keyword after the type. In many situations that is the only way to exactly specify what part of the type const is.

You are using `const T*` (or `T const *`). where `T` is `MemberInfo*`:

```
LinkedList<MemberInfo*>::CreateLinkedList(
```

So the full type is `MemberInfo * const *`. Note that this is not the same as `const MemberInfo * *` (or `MemberInfo const * *`).